# Java Reflection - serviceCall

Tags: java, reflection

I want to call a Webservice with Reflection, because I generate all Webservice Files dynamically at runtime.

This is the Code statement:

```
 List<ResultObject> resObject = transaction.executeServiceCall("webservicename", new String[] { "webserviceInput" }, new Object[] { serviceList }, ResultObject.class);
```

The Declaration of the input parameters:

```
    Object resultObject = "com.test.ResultObject"; 
    String webservicename = "webservicename"; // from the choosen Webservice
    String webserviceinput = "webserviceInput; // from the choosen Webservice
   List<WebserviceInputObject> siList = new ArrayList<WebserviceInputObject>();
```

How can I call the executeServiceCall dynamically with the given Paramers?

Second Question is how to realize that construct with reflection:

```
 List<WebserviceInputObject> siList = new ArrayList<WebserviceInputObject>()
```

WebserviceInputObject is a Object, which also has to be loaded by java reflection

Answer (score 0):

To invoke

```
Class[] argTypes = { String.class, String[].class, Object[].class, Class.class };
Method method = transaction.getClass().getMethod("executeServiceCall", argTypes);
Object[] args = { resultObject, webservicename, webserviceinput, siList  };
List<ResultObject> resObject = (List) method.invoke(transaction, args);
```

To create a WebserviceInputObject

```
WebserviceInputObject instance = WebserviceInputObject.class.newInstance();
Method nameSetter = WebserviceInputObject.class.getMethod("setName", String.class);
// use xDeclaredY methods for private methods/fields
Field typeField = WebserviceInputObject.class.getDeclaredField("type");
typeField.setAccessible(true); // make private field settable
nameSetter.invoke(instance, "foo");
typeField.set(instance, 666);
...
```